# Make PHP site, then implement Laravel or build on Laravel from the get go?

Tags: php, laravel

**Should I:**

A. make this medium to possibly huge website with PHP first and then
    implement Laravel

or

B. Learn Laravel now and build the site with Laravel from the get go?

About the site I want to make:

- Scalable - it can handle 200 or 200,000 users using the site at the
  same time.
- It will mostly run on text entries, calendar functions, lists, some
  social networking within and outside the site
- I want the customer to not experience lag.
- I will most likely be the only person working on the coding.
- Each user will not be able to upload pictures or videos at the
  beginning of the project, but I would like to allow it as the site
  grows to maybe 15-30MB/user.
- Credit card processing or Paypal will be used as a recurring charge.
- I'd like to start small and grow with the customer base
- Due to cash flow Cash flow I'd like to use the least amount of $ possible in the beginning
- I may pass it off to someone else in the future if it gets too big
  too fast

*About me:*

- After a lot of research it looks like Laravel is the PHP MVC
  framework that will stand the test of time (5 years~ hopefully)
- First time asking a question - this site has helped me so much over
  the years!
- Just learning PHP, Javascript, SASS, MySQL, etc, because I have an
  idea and no money to hire someone else.
- I do enjoy creating things though and have enjoyed HTML, CSS, and VBA
  in the past.

Answer (score 2):

If you in near future wanna implement the site with laravel I think you should do it now even if it delays you for 1/2 week to understand laravel clearly. Because as days go by your codebase grows larger and you'll neither have time nor will to convert it rather than adding new features :)

Answer (score 1):

**Jump right into Laravel if you are new to PHP**

1. Install the [Homestead virtual machine](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead)
2. Follow the entire [Laravel From Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch) series
3. Do the [Basic Task List](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart) app

Then explore some more of [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com) and go from there.

Bonus:

- Get [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)
- Use git version control
- Get a [GitHub](https://github.com) account and store your code in a private repo ($7/mo)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely start with Laravel. It will significantly improve your development time and make your code more maintainable. This is specially true if you are just starting with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Learning PHP first is also good, but if you are trying to create an application also i'd suggest learning Laravel First, this would improve your overall knowledge about how MVC frameworks work, and laravel's awesome features.

To learn laravel, check out this link: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want to use Laravel sound knowledge of PHP is a must. Laravel is based on MVC(Model View Controller) model. So it wont be that much difficult to handle as there are several tutorials on MVC. You get the PHP OOPS fundamentals and then jump to Laravel.